# What does *(void **) mean?

Tags: c++, c

I saw a sentence in the program

```
void *tmp = ...
tmp =  *(void **)ptr2;
```

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: it means `tmp` takes the content put in the address stored in `ptr2`.

Comment: It's a syntax error. Please update your question to show us the actual code, which presumably doesn't have the double parentheses.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, it doesn't; see my comment.

Comment: `((void **))ptr2` is a cast, and *cast_result is dereferencing pointer

Comment: @Kastaneda: No, a cast uses only a single set of parentheses.

Comment: Is the code from a C program or from a C++ program? Why did you use both tags?

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, i think OP means single set of parentheses. But i have black belt by CopyPaste art :)

Comment: A very minor point: statements and declarations are not generally referred to as "sentences".

Comment: I didn't make up these codes. It's just written so and works fine without syntax errors, but I don't understand.

Comment: @MartinGGWW: Did the original code include the `...`? Did it *really* have two sets of parentheses? It matters. Please copy and paste the *exact* code from the source file. Don't re-type it; that risks introducing errors that aren't in the original source.

Comment: I am guessing you meant: `(*(void**)`. I can't find a reference just yet but IRC `void*` is a pointer to data **not** functions. However some things (like `dlsym()`) want to return arbitrary function pointers. This is not technically legal but a *workaround* that is *supposed to work* in *most* cases is the casting to a `void**` before re-casting to `void*` (or something like that). Still looking to confirm.

Comment: I am very sure it's *(void **) ptr2

Comment: Ok. **To quote *"The Linux Programming Interface"*:** "...the C99 standard forbids assignment between a function pointer and void *. The solution is to use the following (somewhat clumsy) cast:
*(void **) (&funcp) = dlsym(handle, symbol);" - maybe someone wants to incorporate that into their answer?

Comment: @MartinGGWW: Great. Now update your question to be consistent with what you just wrote. Your question has double parentheses. Your recent comment does not. And yes, **it matters**.

Comment: @Galik: We have no evidence that there are any function pointers involved. A simple cast of the `void*` value returned by `dlsym()` to the appropriate pointer-to-function type *should* work, but gcc complains "warning: ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type [-Wpedantic]". In fact ISO C does not forbid such conversions; it merely leaves their behavior undefined. Such a cast does not violate a constraint or syntax rule.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well I could argue that the evidence for function pointers is that the expression is idiomatic of casting to function pointers. ;o) From what I have herd (not an expert) function pointers do not need to be the same size as data pointers and because `void*` is a data pointer it is *possible* that a function pointer won't fit. Therefore it is UB to cast *through* void* and the compiler complains. But I couldn't find any reference info on that.

Comment: @Galik: Yes, it's UB. It's not forbidden, as gcc incorrectly claims. And `dlsym()` and friends depend on the assumption that you can convert from `void*` to a function pointer without loss of information (which means they won't work on systems with fat function pointers).

Comment: @MartinGGWW : "I am very sure it's *(void **) ptr2" - So are we, but that is not what you have written in the question.  You should fix the question!

Comment: I've rolled back two recent edits that changed the code in the question. The OP has not yet given us a consistent picture of the actual code he's asking about. He's posted a comment with what appears to be correct code, but has neither edited the question nor acknowledged the inconsistency. One of the edits in particular was made by someone who posted an answer that assumes the "corrected" version of the code in the question. The edit was very likely correct, but we should wait for the OP to fix his own question. See [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/827263) on Meta.

Comment: The OP has not been on the site in the past 17 hours as I write this, so he's presumably not aware of this discussion. I've also voted to close this question as "unclear what you're asking". My major concern is that if someone else "fixes" the code in the question, the OP will fail to learn how to ask good questions. (Yes, that's dangerously close to being condescending, but I'm too lazy to come up with a better way to phrase it.)

Comment: Too all those emploring the OP to fix the question to match `*(void**)`, why not just fix it yourself? @KeithThompson:  I edited the OP.  This edit amounts to fixing a minor syntax error.  Leaving the syntax error and downvoting the question isn't making the site better, nor is it teaching OP any kind of lesson.  Just make the post better and move on.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I understand what you're saying, and I disagree. Correcting errors *in code* in a question is very risky. And to be blunt, you posted an answer based on your *assumption* of what the OP really meant, and then changed the code in the question to match your answer. This issue has been discussed on meta ([here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/827263), please read if you haven't already), and the conclusion was that "Code in questions should only be edited for formatting and readability." I stand by what I've said previously, but I don't want to get into an edit war.

Comment: Yes, my answer was posted based on my assumptions, but the OP later confirmed my assumptions to be correct.  I'm willing to agree to disagree, but in the face of the fact that the OP is likely never going to come back to this question again in addition to the fact that it is now obvious what the OP should have been, IMV holding to the rules you linked for the sake of the rules alone is short-sighted and rigid.

Comment: @MartinGGWW: Please confirm that the code now in the question (as edited by others) actually matches the code you're asking about. Also, what is `ptr2`?

Answer (score 4):

```
tmp =  *(void **)ptr2;
```

Let's take this a step at a time.

```
void *
```

This is pointer-to-void.

```
void **
```

This is pointer-to-pointer-to-void.

```
(void **)ptr2;
```

Whatever `ptr2` is, let's cast it to pointer-to-pointer-to-void.

```
*(void **)ptr2;
```

Let's de-reference the pointer-to-pointer-to-void, yielding a pointer-to-void.

```
tmp =  *(void **)ptr2;
```

Assign that pointer-to-void to `tmp`.

Comment: Is it legal to dereference `void **` ?

Comment: the code won't be compiled in the first place... either the right paren is in the wrong place or the outer paren should not be there.

Comment: This is definitely a syntax error in C89 and C99. `t3.c:3:19: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token \n
 tmp =  *((void **))ptr2;`

Comment: @haccks absolutely. as long as you don't dereference `void *`.

Comment: @haccks:  Sure it's legal.

Comment: As  @KiethThompson has pointed out (twice) in comments to the original question. `((void**))ptr2` *is not* a valid cast - it will not compile.

Comment: @haccks: Of course it's legal. Dereferencing a value of type `void**` gives you an lvalue of type `void*`, which is a perfectly valid object type. (But you can't do it with syntactically invalid code, which both the question and this answer attempt to do.)

Comment: @KeithThompson; Actually I got confused with the fact that dereferencing `void *` is invalid. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: -1 to the answer. `((void **))ptr2;` is not a valid C/C++ syntax.

Comment: why people vote down to @John Dibling? I think his explanation is very helpful!

Comment: @MartinGGWW:  People get hung up on trivial minutiae when it is quite obvious what the question really is.  In any case, I addressed the syntax error.

Comment: @Clifford:  Even still, it was intuitively obvious to even the most casual observer what the point of the question was.  So I chose to answer the *question*, rather than find a reason to criticize the method in which it was asked.  In any case, I edited the post.

Comment: You still don't *mention* the syntax error. I chose not to try to guess what the OP meant. It's not obvious that `tmp =  *((void **))ptr2;` was intended to be `tmp =  *(void **)ptr2;`. The number of `*`s could have been incorrect, for all we know. The question can be a good one *if the OP will correct it*.

Comment: @JohnDibling : I agree; and if the OP chooses to fix the question, your answer is fine - down-voting was downright harsh IMO.  I merely suggest that you mention your interpretation of the question in the answer.  I think Keith's aim was to improve the quality of the question first - if you answer anyway, the OP may not care enough to fix it.  I am going to fix it in any case.

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation would be more clear given more context (and if it were syntactically valid and compilable code).

Consider:

```
int i = 10 ;                  // an object i
int* ptr = &i ;               // ptr = address of i
int** ptr2 = &ptr ;           // ptr2 = address of ptr

void* tmp = *(void**)ptr2;    // tmp = thing pointed to by ptr2,
                              //       which is ptr, which is in turn the address of i,
                              //       but without type information.
```

Now, what that means semantically in the original code is unknowable without seeing the original code.

Comment: But note that casting an `int**` to a `void**` is undefined behavior, although casting an `int**` to `void*` is defined.

Comment: @cdhowie The cast isn't undefined. Using the result is.

Comment: I am not recommending this code, merely answering the question.  The code certainly has a smell about it - especially if it is C++ as tagged.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recommended *workaround* for those occasions when you need to cast a `void*` to a function pointer. For example the [dlsym()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) function.

**To quote the man page:**

> Writing: cosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos"); would
>   seem more natural, but the C99 standard leaves casting from "void *"
>   to a function pointer undefined. The assignment used below is the
>   POSIX.1-2003 (Technical Corrigendum 1) workaround; see the Rationale
>   for the POSIX specification of dlsym().

Comment: So to "fix" the undefined behavior in the cast they chose to introduce a UB-causing strict aliasing violation instead. Nice.

Comment: @T.C. Well `dlsym()` has a difficult to solve problem and they solve it in a way that violates defined behaviour. So I guess they just recommended something that should *usually* work (because *most* systems tolerate it) just to shut the compiler up.

Answer (score -1):

It means whatever the value stored in memory location pointed by ptr2 is treated as a memory location and is referred by tmp.
equivalent:
    tmp = (void*)*ptr2

Comment: No, that's not equivalent. For one thing, `tmp = (void*)*ptr2` is not a syntax error.

Comment: oops didn't saw two brackets. tmp =  *(void **)ptr2 wouldn't have started the syntax war here.